# dynamically making nsarry from the static content in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsarray

I  have to use a code to make a NSArray using the below code Objective C

```
self.sampleData = @[ @{ @"description": @"Section A",
                      @"articles": @[ @{ @"title": @"Article A1" },
                                      @{ @"title": @"Article A2" },
                                      @{ @"title": @"Article A3" },
                                      @{ @"title": @"Article A4" },
                                      @{ @"title": @"Article A5" }
                                      ]
                      } ];
```

How could I write same code in swift that too dynamically lets say in a loop, I want to initialise Article A1, Article A2 string like for 5 elements there will be Article 5.

Comment: Why show obj-c code that doesn't answer the question you have? What have you tried so far for your question about a loop?

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea how to do this. If I would have known, I could have written it already

Comment: Start with a mutable array and a loop, add things to it, then add it to something else. Have a go and show your attempt, explaining what it does wrong, if you have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about your Swift knowledge but here is one way to make an array procedurally:

```
// in Swift you are using the type Array instead of NSArray
var sampleData = [[String : AnyObject]]() // empty Array of dictionaries
sampleData["description"] = "Section A"

var articles = [[String : String]]() // empty Array of dictionaries

// is the same as   for var i = 1; i <= 5; i++ {
for i in 1...5 {
    let article = [String : String]()
    article["title"] = "Article A\(i)" // using String interpolation
    articles.append(dict)
}

// add articles to sampleData
sampleData["articles"] = articles
```

Due to Swifts functional method `map` you can also rewrite this to:

```
var sampleData = [[String : AnyObject]]() // empty Array of dictionaries
sampleData["description"] = "Section A"

let articles = (1...5).map{ Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("title", "Article A\($0)")) }

// add articles to sampleData
sampleData["articles"] = articles
```

As general advice if you want to use such a data structure as storage you should consider making new structs or classes like `Section` and `Article` to have a more static compiler checked one.